# Python TypedDict: functional syntax when inheriting another TypedDict

Tags: python, typing, typeddict

Given this type:

```py
class TPerson(TypedDict):
  name: str
  address: str
```

I want another `TypedDict` inheriting the previous one, like:

```py
class TDealer(TPerson):
  db-id: int
  police_record: str
  arrested_now: bool
  
class TConsumer(TPerson):
  db-id: int
  preferred_product: str
  stoned_now: bool
```

But, since `db-id` [is not a valid identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), [I need to use functional syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) both for `TDealer` and `TConsumer`.

Is it possible to inherit from another `TypedDict` using functional syntax?

I see `TypedDict` definition is like:

```py
class _TypedDict(Mapping[str, object], metaclass=ABCMeta):
```

But not sure 100% if this is a No!

If not, which could be a nice workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, but there are a number of workarounds.

Including the fields of `TPerson` directly into its "subclasses":

```
TDealer = TypedDict('TDealer', {'name': str, 'address': str, 'db-id': int, 'police_record': str, 'arrested_now': bool}

TConsumer = TypedDict('TConsumer', {'name': str, 'address': str, 'db-id': int, 'preferred_product': str, 'stoned_now': bool})
```

Making mix-ins:

```
class TPerson(TypedDict):
    name: str
    address: str

TDealer = TypedDict('TDealer', {'db-id': int, 'police_record': str, 'arrested_now': bool}

TConsumer = TypedDict('TConsumer', {'db-id': int, 'preferred_product': str, 'stoned_now': bool})

class TDealer(TDealer, TPerson):
    pass

class TConsumer(TConsumer, TPerson):
    pass
```

Both subclasses share `db-int`, so you could consider moving that to `TPerson`:

```
TPerson = TypedDict('TPerson', {'name': str, 'address': str, 'db-id': int})

class TDealer(TPerson):
    police_record: str
    arrested_now: bool
  
class TConsumer(TPerson):
    preferred_product: str
    stoned_now: bool
```

Comment: I like the Mixins solution, but, when doing `class TDealerMixin(TDealer, TPerson)`, i get the pylint error `inheriting TDealer, which is not a class`. Is it ignorable?

Comment: Either pylint (or the version of pylint you have) doesn't support `TypedDict` or it has a bug. What happens if you ignore that error?